# SSH to remote machine without domain name?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, fedora

So I've been trying to SSH into my PC running Fedora. The problem is that I've never used SSH before, and have no clue about how to SSH into my machine.

My machine's host name is redhat, and the username is archvbx.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ssh redhat@99.88.77.66
ssh archvbx@redhat
ssh archvbx@99.88.77.66
```

And of course, none of these works. If someone could reuse the IP, user, and hostname, that would be great. Any additional information requested can probably be added.

Comment: Can you ping that IP? Is the ssh client excutable being found?

Comment: That IP is just an example, but I just tried to ping that IP and it doesn't work. Seems I need to get the IP from the actual PC. Still, once I have that IP, how would I connect.

Comment: The command should be `ssh archvbx@99.88.77.66`. You can also type: `echo "99.88.77.66 redhat" >> /etc/hosts` to add the name to you hosts file. Then it's: `ssh archvbx@redhat` . But I definately wouldn't actually use simply 'redhat' as a name for a server.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's the solution, but just one quick question (and sorry for it.): Why is redhat a bad name for a server?

Comment: Because that is an OS name. Make it something related to what it does and give it a number. FileServer01, FS1, FileServ01, RHFS01 etc.. anything is better. This keeps it easy to find in a large list of them.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a system to accept SSH connections the system must first be running the SSH server. By default, Fedora Linux installs the SSH server so it is not usually necessary to install it. To check if it is installed and running use the following command:

> /sbin/service sshd status

If your machine allready running this Service you should have a result something like this:

> sshd (pid 9488 9486 1850) is running...

If the service is not installed it can be installed as follows:

> su -
>
> yum install openssh-server

The installation process with download the SSH server, install it and start the service running in the background. You may now attempt to connect from a remote system. If you receive a "connection refused" message when you try to connect it you may need to configure the firewall to allow SSH connections to be established to this system.

If the service is installed, but not running, it can be started either from the command-line:

> /sbin/service sshd start

The service may also be started by using the GUI Service Configuration tool accessed via the System->Administration->Services menu option. Once the tool has loaded, simply scroll down the list of services until you reach sshd. Select it and click on the Start button located in the toolbar.

Comment: That's not the problem I'm having. I'm having issues knowing about how to connect one it is running.

Comment: ssh Username@Host/IP or ssh -l username ipaddresss/host

Comment: That syntax is what I am having the issues with. For username, would I put redhat which is my PC's hostname or archvbx which is redhat's user?

Comment: And just for the record, I have multiple devices on my network, which is part of what is confusing me.

Comment: Username refers to Username, not to Machine Name. And as hostname/ip you will just have to put your machine's IP. Be sure you have Forwarded port 22 on your Firewall/Router for Remote Connections. You can try connect in your own terminal by doing this: ssh -l archvbx 127.0.0.1 , to see if its working.